# Indy 9 with Delphi: How to enable TLS 1.0?

Tags: delphi, indy

I cannot find docs or examples that show how to code up an http client to use TLS1.0 protocol as default, and only fall back to SSL v3 if the TLS connection fails.

Where to find?

Comment: Does Indy have any documentation? I have a feeling you need to read the code to work out how to use it. Or am I maligning it?

Comment: [Indy has documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.EN.aspx), it is just not up-to-date.

Comment: I would note: The Indy 9 docs.... I don't see anything useful related to "here is how to do tls" or anything like that...

Comment: @Remy That's almost worse than no documentation at all!

Comment: I can find nothing useful in any docs related to TLS vs SSL, or how to handle the issue generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, and then set the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Method` property to `sslvTLSv1` for TLS v1.0 specifically, or to `sslvSSLv23` to let `TIdHTTP` and the server dynamically negotiate a compatible version during handshaking.  Then have `TIdHTTP` request an HTTPS url.

Comment: Thanks!  But if I use sslvSSLv23, that will start w TLS 1.0, then shift if nec to SSL ?  (The docs are silent, apologies!)

Comment: SSLv23 is a wildcard that performs version negotiation during the handshake. It will end up using the highest SSL/TLS version that both parties support. If both support TLS 1.0 as the highest common version, TLS 1.0 will be used. If one supports TLS 1.0 and the other supports SSL 3.0 as the highest, SSL 3.0 will be used.

Comment: Remy, Thank you!  Is that documented anywhere?